# How to transfer switch state to Simulink block from m file?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to control the switch from m file. I want to use 'if action' block to make it and the 'if action' block is controlled by Matlab function. The input of Matlab function is from m file.

The Simulink is as following:
[image]

The Matlab function's code is as following:

```
function y = fcn_test(x1, x2)

y = x1 + x2;
```

Now I want to transfer the input, eg x1 and x2, of Matlab function from m file. The m file is as following:

```
clc

global x1
global x2
x1 = 1;
x2 = 2;

a = fcn_test(x1, x2);

disp(a)
```

The bug is `Simulink model 'fcn_test' was called with incorrect number of arguments`.  So what is the problem of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have a model and a m file with the name `fcn_test`. You are actually calling the model function described [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/model_cmd.html) and not your m code. Rename one of the two.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I know that the Matlab function can not be called in m file now. But how to transfer the value from m file to simulink?